# How to provide more functionality for attribute methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to provide more functionality for attribute methods. That is:

Given I have the following model class

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

And given `Article` instances have the following attribute methods

```
@article.title   # => "Sample title"
@article.content # => "Sample content"
```

Then I would like to add to `Article` functionality as like the following:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def title(args)
    # Some logic...

    self.title
  end

  def content(args)
    # Some logic...

    self.content
  end
end

@article.title(args)
@article.content(args)
```

Is the above approach safe / correct / valid? Will I have issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you read [7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/). What you want can be a nice decorator or value object.

```
class Title
  def initialize(article)
    @article = article
  end

  def weird_title
    some_logic
  end
end
```

and when the `weird_title` is needed on an article `article_1`

```
Title(article_1).weird_title
```

Thus you have a good code separation (OOP style) and you keep your model clean.

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding `title` and `content` methods, and as far as I know this approach isn't safe at all. Like, having getter and setter methods is a completely different story. But, this pattern will confuse you and other developers after some time.

And if I'm right(correct me if I'm wrong, please), you must get 
`wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error for `title` and `content` at line number where you have:

`self.title` and `self.content` when you do:

```
@article.title(args)
@article.content(args)
```

Comment: You could address the `number of arguments` with `def title(args=nil)` but i agree that this is a bad thing to do.  It will cause confusion.

Comment: Yes, good point. You can address the issue with: `def title(args=nil)`. I was focusing on what OP asked though. :)